# How to pass a variable (array of strings) to other PowerShell scripts

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a variable, $Tasks, in a PowerShell script that contains an array of strings, and I need to pass the variable along to other PowerShell scripts and do stuff with it, like loop through the array and do things with each item (string).

However, at some point along the way my variable gets converted from an array to a string (usually when it hits script2.ps1), and I'm not able to loop through it. What do I need to do to keep the variable as an array throughout the entire process?

Here is the workflow of the variable:

**Script1.ps1**:

```
$Tasks = @(
"Task1 - Name1",
"Task2 - Name2",
"Task3 - Name3"
)

powershell "& {. $pwd\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum; Run-Validation -Tasks $Tasks}"
```

**Script2.ps1**:

```
param(
    $Tasks=$()
)

Function Run-Validation
{
    param($Tasks)

    If ($Tasks)
    {
        Test-Tasks $Tasks
    }
}
```

**Script3.ps1**:

```
Function Test-Tasks ($Tasks)
{
    ForEach ($Task in $Tasks)
    {
        do_stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you're expanding an array, `$Tasks`, inside a double-quoted string. Before your command line is passed to PowerShell.exe, it is expanded to:

```
Arg 0 is <& {. C:\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum ; Run-Validation -Tasks Task1 - Name1 Task2 - Name2 Task3 - Name3}>
```

So the `Run-Validation -Tasks` parameter only sees "Task1". If you were to look at $args inside of the Run-Validation function you would see the rest of the arguments.

BTW, why invoke another Powershell.exe session? Why not just invoke like so:

```
. $PSScriptRoot\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum
Run-Validation -Tasks $Tasks
```

Note that the above only works *if* you eliminate the script level $Tasks parameter in Script2.ps1. If not, when you dot source Script2.ps1 to gain access to the Run-Validation function, the $Tasks in Script2.ps1 effectively overwrites the value set in Script1.ps1.

If you really want to invoke this in a separate PowerShell session you can do this:

```
$OFS="','"
powershell "& {. $pwd\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum; Run-Validation -Tasks '$Tasks'}"
```

Comment: Hi Keith, if I omit the param block then no values get passed in at all. With the param block, the value of $Tasks gets passed thru as a string.

Comment: So why aren't you using the -Tasks parameter when you invoke script2.ps1? Also you do use a -BuildNum parameter that isn't declared in your scriptblock.

Comment: My above example is an extremely trimmed down version of my actual script. -BuildNum is actually declared in my script in the param block of Script2.ps1 as a string:  [string]$BuildNum=$() in addition to many other parameters that I pass in (all of them are strings). If I actually create the variable $Tasks in Script1.ps1 as a single string (i.g. $Tasks = 'Task1 - Name1'), then everything works nicely. In fact, all my variables are strings since they contain the value of a single thing. With $Tasks, I have more than one thing to process which is why I thought of putting then into an array.

Comment: Hi Keith, sorry, not sure what you mean by this question: "why aren't you using the -Tasks parameter when you invoke script2.ps1?"

Comment: `C:\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum` - you run Script2.ps1 and pass in an argument for the BuildNum parameter but you don't pass in a value for the Tasks parameter.

Comment: Hi Keith, I understand what you said about $Tasks getting expanded because it's in double-quotes. And your example to use $OFS="','" and wrap $Tasks in single-quotes (i.e. '$Tasks') looks like it solved my problem. The array is getting persisted thru the other scripts. Thanks heaps for the great input!

Comment: Also, I tried your other method of calling the script this way but it would not work for me: `. $PSScriptRoot\Script2.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum
Run-Validation -Tasks $Tasks`

Comment: Yeah that won't work unless you get rid of the Tasks parameter in the script level params() block on Script2.ps1.  Because that exists and is set to an empty array *and* you dot source into the current scope, its value stomps the $Tasks value set in script1.ps1.

Comment: Re *"...on sees "Task1"*: Do you mean *"...only sees "Task1"*?

Comment: Yes, should be "only". i'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to structure my PowerShell scripts as functions. Instead of passing the $Tasks all the way through multiple scripts, I recommend pulling in the $Tasks when you are ready to use them.

This would be the equivalent of your *Script1.ps1*.

**taskList.ps1**

```
Function Get-Tasks()
{
    $Tasks = @(
        "Task1 - Name1",
        "Task2 - Name2",
        "Task3 - Name3"
    )
    return $Tasks
}
```

This would be the equivalent of your *Script2.ps1* and *Script3.ps1* combined:

```
# Dot source the scripts we will need
.$PSScriptRoot\taskList.ps1

# Get the list of tasks
$taskList = Get-Tasks

if ($taskList -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($task in $taskList)
    {
        # Do stuff here
        "Processing task: " + $task
    }
}
```

**Note:** *$PSScriptRoot* will load from the current working directory. If this file is located elsewhere, use the full path.

However, if you would still like to keep your current structure, you can simply update *Script.1* to the following

```
# Dot source the scripts we will need
.$PSScriptRoot\Script3.ps1

$Tasks = @(
    "Task1 - Name1",
    "Task2 - Name2",
    "Task3 - Name3"
)

Run-Validation -Tasks $Tasks
```

Comment: Hi Beard, my example above is a very simplified version of my actual script. Script1.ps1 is actually an install/deployment script that contains multiple variables (each usually contains value of a string), function calls, and general workflow tasks to install/deploy things on a server. Once the install is complete I call from Script1.ps1 a validation script to validate what was just installed. This is Script2.sp1. It contains a parameter list, functions calls, and serves as the workflow for the validation, and it calls Script3.ps1, which contains all my functions.

Comment: There is also a 4th script for reporting. To add, Script2.ps1, Script3.ps1, and Script4.ps1 used to all be in a single script, but over time the monolithic script became too large and unwieldy to maintain, which is why I decided to break them up by functional purpose (workflow, functions, reporting). Anyway, if I give my variable $Tasks a single value of a string (e.g. "task name") then everything works nicely. In fact all the variables that I pass in contain a value of a string. This is the first time I've tried passing in a variable as an array, which is not working thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I am using such a definition of parameters inside the script:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [Alias("cn", "name")]
    [String[]]$var
)
```

In this example you can define: `[String]$var`as a single string variable, or `[String[]]$var` as a array of string variables.