# Passing parameters to multiple PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

My ultimate goal is to provision email in Office 365 from Active Directory using PowerShell.  The first script calls a second, the second calls a third and a fourth, the fourth calls the fifth & final script.  I need to pass parameters to the first script and the parameters need to end up in the final script (which does all the work) but I am having issues passing them through all of scripts to end up in the final script.

Each script contains the following at the beginning of the script to receive the parameters:

```
param(
    [string]$empl_status, 
    [string]$emplid, 
    [string]$union_cd, 
    [string]$location, 
    [string]$job_function, 
    [string]$dn, 
    [string]$cn
)
```

To pass the parameters to the next script, each script's call to the next script looks like this:

```
. "c:\rsa\connectexch.ps1" -empl_status="$empl_status" -emplid="$emplid" -union_cd="$union_cd" -location="$location" -job_function="$job_function" -dn="$dn" -cn="$cn"
```

I have been scouring the internet but am not finding any documentation that will pass the parameters through the 5 scripts.  I am obviously doing it wrong as the final script just ends because it has no parameters to process.  My guess that this is a process that I do not know the name of, since I am fairly new to PowerShell.

This is an article that I found that sent me in the direction above - [How to pass a variable (array of strings) to other PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574918/how-to-pass-a-variable-array-of-strings-to-other-powershell-scripts).  I have also spoken with two other heavy PowerShell users and they have confirmed that this is how to do pass parameters to multiple scripts.

Hoping this makes sense to someone and I can get some help.  I don't know where else to go for help...

Comment: Did you try to [debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) your script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830555/splatting-subproperty might help, not sure if it's really a duplicate though

Comment: Try removing the equal signs.  Rather than `-empl_status="$empl_status"` try `-empl_status $empl_status`

Comment: @BenH is correct in his suggestion but why the Rube-Goldberg machine of scripts?  if you want to keep your functionality in seperate files make everything functions and dot source them. into a single main script that does your work, having a chain of scripts is going to be a nightmare to maintain and debug.

Comment: Another other option is `Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)`

Answer (score 0):

My script I used to test my solution

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$p1,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$p2,

$stop
)


Write-Verbose "P1: $p1" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "P1: $p2" -Verbose

if(!$stop)
{
. .\connectexch.ps1 @PSBoundParameters -stop $true
}
```

So the solution is:

```
. "c:\rsa\connectexch.ps1" @PSBoundParameters
```

This is called splatting. PSBoundParameters is a built-in hashtable of all the parameters supplied to the function (calling a ps1 is treated like a function call.)

Comment: I created a [topic request](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/topic-requests/23198) to doc the built-in variables